# Equally distribute text within CSS column property

Tags: javascript, html, css, multiple-columns

I've divided a text into 4 columns with CSS column property and the result is something like [this](http://s10.postimg.org/5efo02el5/Capture11.jpg)

Now what i would like to do is to equally distribute the text in a way that i could get something like [this](http://s8.postimg.org/n4eoty4px/Capture12.jpg)

Code:

```css
#container {
background: rgba(255, 237, 0, 1.00);
width: 100%;
-webkit-column-count: 4;
-webkit-column-gap: 15px;
-webkit-column-rule: 2px solid lightblue;
-moz-column-count: 4;
-moz-column-gap: 15px;
-moz-column-rule: 2px solid lightblue;
column-count: 4;
column-gap: 15px;
column-rule: 2px solid lightblue;
}
```

```html
<section id="container">
  "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."

</section>
```

Comment: What code have you tried so far? (You can add code using the "Code Snippet" button. Or you could create a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to demonstrate your attempts.)

Comment: i would suggest to put delimiters inside th text (e.g dummy elements like `<br class="delimiter" />`) and use them in css to break text as you wish, the delimiters can be placed manually or even with javascript counting text length etc

Comment: @jsve there is the code I'm using, if it can be done with javascript or jquery, there is no problem with me, but i would like to keep it as simple as possible

Comment: @NikosM. yeah that sounds like it might work, would you mind providing and example please?, although it wouldn't raise the problem of how to equally distribute the delimiters inside the columns?

Comment: @MarcoCastro, hmm this is a hint, do not have the time right now, maybe later tomorrow if no answer has been found untill then

Answer (score 0):

You might be running into browser support issues. Check out http://caniuse.com/#search=columns to see how supported columns are right now.

See this Jsfiddle for an example with browser prefixes that seem to do what you are asking for
https://jsfiddle.net/82dnb1ab/

```
#container {
  background: rgba(255, 237, 0, 1.00);
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-column-count: 4;
  -webkit-column-gap: 15px;
  -webkit-column-rule: 2px solid lightblue;
  -moz-column-count: 4;
  -moz-column-gap: 15px;
  -moz-column-rule: 2px solid lightblue;
  column-count: 4;
  column-gap: 15px;
  column-rule: 2px solid lightblue;
}
```

Comment: thats not the OP's question.

Comment: than you will, but it would not solve my problem, i need the text to be equally distributed between the columns, any idea of how to do that?

Comment: @MarcoCastro Have you looked at the column-fill rule? http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/#cf I was playing with setting that to "balanced" and it seems to do a pretty good job of evening out the columns. I'm using Chrome 42 if you're not, maybe what you are seeing is a browser difference.